# Efficient Approach for Maximizing the number of Pairs

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, greedy

This is an interview Question that I encountered recently . 
You have G guests  (numbered from 1 to G)  in a party.Each Guest has a preference list of length G which represents his  preferences to talk with others. 
For example if the preference list of guest 1 is N Y N N Y (assuming 5 guests), then Guest 1 is interested to talk to either 2 or 5 but not others.

Assume that

a) Each guest can talk to only one other guest
b) If a is interested in talking to b , then b is also interested in talking to a

Given a matrix of guests and their preferences , Give maximum No of pairs that can be kept engaged.

```
Let G = 5;
```

The  Preference matrix be

```
N Y N N N
Y N Y Y Y
N Y N N N
N Y N N N
N Y N N N
```

As We can observe everyone is interested in talking to Guest 2 but he can talk only to one other person and so the answer is 1 pair.

My Approach:

I thought of it as a Maximum matching Problem in graph theory but unable to implement it 
in the short time frame.(I am not good in Graph Algo Implementation)

Is this solved only using graphs or is there some better , faster approach?
Is there any Greedy Approach ?

Comment: There's no simpler combinatorial way to do this than Edmonds's blossom algorithm.  (At least, none known.)  There's a [fun linear algebra trick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_matrix), though.

Answer (score 1):

We can use recursion and some memoization.  Please find a way to recognize a graph with K nodes and all relationships (we'll see below why we need this).  During recursion we should record already solved cases (K, R) where K is the number of guests and R is the list of relationships of these K guests.

For the problem (N, R) we would number guests as 1, 2, ..., N, then scan through list of relationships to get a list with no repetition (a hash table may help checking for duplicates)

1 & 2, 1 & 4, 2 & 3, etc.

We need to find maximum of non-colliding pairs (for example, 1 & 2 collides with 2 & 3).  We can use the following recursive algorithm:

A) if 1 & 2 is taken, then remove all pairs with 1 or 2, and do recursion on the rest.

R<sub>A</sub> will be the list of remaining relationships without 1 and 2.  And we have recursion of ((N-2), R<sub>A</sub>)

B) if 1 & 2 are skipped, do recursion with the rest.

R<sub>B</sub> will be the list of remaining relationships without the link (1 & 2).  And we have recursion of (N, R<sub>B</sub>) - still N because 1 or 2 may still remain in the full set.

C) Check what route render a bigger number of pairs.

We need memoization to store results of (K, R) because there may be clusters of guests like (1, 3, 5, ...) and (2, 4, 6, ...) where guests are friends of each other just inside the clusters.

If we use naive recursion, we'll solve the same problems many times.  But the clusters mean that their solutions are symmetrical.  Therefore we need to recognize the graphs by the combination of number of guests and their relationships (renumbering guests produces the same graph).

Comment: See Gangnus' answer.  Removing guests with no friends remaining at each step of recursion is an optimization.

Comment: +1, A good thought you have here, about clusters, but you haven't brought it into the algorithm. I have tried to improve it further.

Comment: @Gangnus a function for (K, R) should take care about identical clusters.
I am still thinking what could be a quick way to recognize that two graphs are identical.  It should be a standard CS topic, but it's fun to think over it on your own.

Comment: Of course, an additional utility for comparison of graphs will be useful, for not to rework the similar subgraphs. Especially that would be useful for smaller graphs.

Comment: @Gangnus - graph comparison turned out to be a quite large topic :)  http://www.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/~saksoy/courses/cs551-Spring2009/papers/conte04_graph_matching.pdf (thirty years of graph matching! And O(n) is proposed only in 2001)

Answer (score 0):

The recursion will split into two principal stages:

**Simplification:**
Remove guests without friends.
Divide graph into non-connected areas.

Further, for every area the next stage will be fulfilled:

**Cutting**
Order the guests up according to number of their friends.
Take the first untried connection into the found pairs list.
Repeat the whole process starting from simplification with the received diminished area until all connections are recursively tried or the number of pairs in the currently build set is equal to [Area power /2].

We could also improve the speed if we'll first try the connections that divide the area into two non-connected areas of *even* power.

Comment: Could you please check my answer?  Ordering perhaps doesn't help much in case of clusters of guests, though removing guests with no friends at each step of recursion is an optimization.